# How can I best resolve this react-native error?

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the error I'm encountering

```
TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object, js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in createErrorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\js-polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.applyWithGuard
at node_modules\metro-config\node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.183.208:19002/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in metroRequire
at http://192.168.183.208:19002/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global
```

I have created a new expo project.
I have installed all necessary dependencies. I expect my app to be displayed on expo go app

Comment: Can you give as more information, which version are you using ?
Did you clean ```watchman watch-del-all```?